# Pass array of parameters to a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Consider the following rails link:

```
search_path(:query => params[:query], type: params[:type], sort: params[:sort])
```

There is a lot of duplication here. Is it possible to define these parameters in an array and they pass into the link? Eg.

```
params: [:query, :type, :sort] # -> pass each into the link like "key: value"
```

Comment: It's bit unclear what you are asking. Do you mean `search_path(:data => [ params[:query], params[:type], params[:sort] ] )`?

Comment: question updated @priya, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of how you could do it exactly passing it as an array like you show, however you could do something like:

```
search_path(params.slice(:query, :type, :sort))
```

This will give you the same hash you're passing in. In my opinion, it's a little cleaner.

```
parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(query: 'query', type: 'type', sort: 'sort', other: 'other')
=> {"query"=>"query", "type"=>"type", "sort"=>"sort", "other"=>"other"}

parameters.slice(:query, :type, :sort)
=> {"query"=>"query", "type"=>"type", "sort"=>"sort"}
```